# Issue with generic taking some unrelated type, in F#

Tags: f#

I have the following code:

```
let exchangeInfo, marginBrackets, accountInfo =
    async {
            let failOrExtract = function
                | Ok    d -> d
                | Error (e: ExchangeError) -> e.Describe |> tee logger.Fatal |> failwith

        let pf = processResult >> failOrExtract

        let! e = rest.FuturesUsdt.System.GetExchangeInfoAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
        let! b = rest.FuturesUsdt.GetBracketsAsync()            |> Async.AwaitTask
        let! i = rest.FuturesUsdt.Account.GetAccountInfoAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask

        return pf e, pf b, pf i
    } |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

In short, it calls 3 async rest functions, then sends them through failOrExtract which is made of 2 parts: the processResult part that returns a Result<'a, ExchangeError> type, **with 'a different for each of these calls**, and then failOrExtract that either fails or returns the data field.

this will not compile, the compiler says:

````
[FS0001] The type 'BinanceFuturesUsdtExchangeInfo' does not match the type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BinanceFuturesSymbolBracket>'```
````

It looks like the failOrExtract function was generic on the first use, but not afterwards since pf e compiles, but pf b and pf i have the same error.

why am I getting this error?

Comment: What is `processResult`?

Comment: It just takes a pseudo result object (a C# object that contains either a null error and ‘a data or a null ‘a data field with an error depending on result) and turns it into a Result<‘a, error>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're running into the F# "value restriction", although the compiler isn't being clear about it. The problem here is that `pf` is defined as a value, not a function, so the compiler is inferring that it has a concrete, non-generic type. In order to give `pf` a generic signature, try changing it to this instead:

```
let pf x = x |> processResult |> failOrExtract
```

Comment: does that mean that function composition can't be using generic types?

Comment: I believe that's correct. The F# [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/automatic-generalization#value-restriction) says "The compiler performs automatic generalization **only on complete function definitions that have explicit arguments**, and on simple immutable values.... If the problem is using a nongeneralizable construct **to define a generic function, such as a function composition** ..., try to rewrite the function as an ordinary function definition." (Emphasis added.)